# WPF Grid won’t resize to fit nested content

Tags: c#, wpf

I’m programmatically inserting grids into grids,  for the first nested, it will work perfect. But then from the second it stops resizing to fit for the content.

The only defaults I override are the MinWidth and the MinHeight.

EDIT:
Each time I'm creating a grid, I add a stackpanel (with lable inside) to each cell. Then I Insert a nested grid to that stack panel.

[image]

As seen above, the grid that's being marked with the green thing, dose not affect the mainGrid size.

Thanks

Comment: Show your work here..

Comment: As I said, the relevant parts are being created in code behind. so the XAML won't be helpful in here. 

I've update my question with some more infor about how I insert the nested grids.

Comment: Use XamlSpy (or such) to look at the generated XAML

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the grid restricts it's maximum size, I don't know for what purpose.

Hopefully that won't back fire at me later. but for now, all I had to do was create and use a custom grid with unlimited 'resize room'.

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        availableSize = new Size(availableSize.Width + double.MaxValue, availableSize.Height + double.MaxValue);
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }
}
```

There are probably more legitimate solutions to this problem, but for the moment that's all I need.